# FFmpeg only and only change H264 profile and level?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I am use FFmpeg v4.1 . I want to change H264 profile and level but I want other settings to stay the same. I just want to change the profile of H264.

I'm using this code, but I'm getting the error.

```
-vcodec copy -profile:v high -level 4.0
```

How can I do that?

Comment: With vcodec copy, you can only change the level using a bitstream filter. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for comment bro. Forget the reason. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `-vcodec copy -bsf:v h264_metadata level=4.0`. Profile can't be changed. ffmpeg version 4.0 or newer required.

Comment: @Gyan it didn't work bro. I have encountered an error:  **[NULL @ 00000072411504c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'level=4.0'
level=4.0: Invalid argument**

Comment: Oops. `-bsf:v h264_metadata=level=4`

Comment: I noticed later too :)

Comment: How do I combine these two codes? `-bsf:v h264_metadata=level=4` `-bsf:v filter_units=remove_types=6`

Comment: `-bsf:v h264_metadata=level=4,filter_units=remove_types=6`

Comment: Thanks for everything, bro. Back to the top; we are unable to modify the H264 profile with the `-vcodec copy` command. I understand this. Well, how do I change the h264 profile without corrupting the original settings?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you cannot copy the video codec as you are changing the video profile, using this command worked for me

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec copy -profile:v high -level 4.0 output.mp4
```

Here I am only copying audio codec.